# UITableView is not calling my cell delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to populate my table view but my delegate method is not being called.

I've binded my table view to my controller.

[image]

I have implemented the protocols, and the delegate methods, as shown below.

```
class TrendsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var listingTable: UITableView!

    var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        listingTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        println("Counting")
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        println("Setting a cell")

        var cell = self.listingTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

When i render the view, i get the following output.

```
Counting
Counting
```

Meaning that the counting is working at least, but why is the cell constructor not being called? What am i missing?

Comment: Have you implemented `numberOfSectionsInTableView(_:)` ?

Comment: I tried, but it did't seem to do it either. :(

Comment: Maybe, your tableView height or width is 0. could you check it out with `println(tableView.frame)`? Any Auto Layout errors in Storyboard?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Somehow xcode had thrown it all the way out of the frame. Please make an answer so that i can accept it. :) Apparently is doesn't call the cell methods, when the frames height and width is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the  height or width of `UITableView` is 0, it never calls `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` delegate method.

You should have been warned by Interface Builder like this:

[image: screenshot]

Click on it, and fix the problems.